# Facebook Graph API like history for page

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have the following question. is it possible to generate a query with the Facebook Graph Explorer which allows a history of the likes per month, but in a longer period of time than with Insights.
Like:
2014 January = 200 Like Count | 2014 February = 195 Like Count | 2014 March = 195 Like Count and so on

Or is there a good software solution for such analyses?

for information:
I am the site owner.

Best regards and thanks in advance!
Benjamin

Comment: _“Or is there a good software solution for such analyses?”_ - _that_ is not a thing to ask here; https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic: _“Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam.”_

Answer (score 0):

Since you are the Page Owner, you can use Page Insights: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/page/insights/

`page_fans` would be the metric you want to use. It may be possible to get a longer period than with the Insights UI. If not, then there is no way to get data that old.